# Как добавить class по атрибуту ссылки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В моем случае `class` добавляется с помощью этой строчки:

```
$(this).filter('[href="'+ anchor +'"]').parent().addClass('current');
```

Есть ли другой метод, с помощью которого можно такое реализовать?

```js
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.header-menu__link').each(function() {
      var anchor = $(this).attr('href');
      if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $(anchor).offset().top - $('.header').outerHeight()) {
        $('.header-menu__item').removeClass('current');
        $(this).filter('[href="' + anchor + '"]').parent().addClass('current');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__inner">
    <menu class="header-menu">
      <li class="header-menu__item current">
        <a href="#trial" class="header-menu__link">Trial</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header-menu__item">
        <a href="#program" class="header-menu__link">Program</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header-menu__item">
        <a href="#gallery" class="header-menu__link">Gallery</a>
      </li>
    </menu>
    <a href="#" class="logo header__logo">
      <img src="img/logo.svg" class="logo__logo" alt="Logo">
    </a>
    <menu class="header-menu">
      <li class="header-menu__item">
        <a href="#about-us" class="header-menu__link">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header-menu__item">
        <a href="#feature" class="header-menu__link">Feature</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header-menu__item">
        <a href="#price" class="header-menu__link">Price</a>
      </li>
    </menu>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему ты так уверен, что все знают html разметку, с которой ты работаешь?

Comment: Eе не нужна знать в этом кейсе. вопрос заключается в том, как элементу добавить класс по атрибуту. зачем тебе полностью код?

Comment: Видимо потому, что ты опираешься на что-то, например на `.parent()`, а, значит, последовательность элементов имеет значение и от этого может зависеть решение. Если же вопрос, как ты говоришь, "как элементу добавить класс по атрибуту", то зачем весь этот ненужный, не относящийся ни к чему код в вопросе? Весь ответ будет сводиться к `$('[href="'+ string +'"]').addClass(someClass);` и тебя можно направить в ближайший учебник по css

Comment: Да, я забыл что в этом кейсе я вешаю класс на родителя этой ссылки, а точнее header-menu__item. Я добавил код. Спасибо что подметил.